# Mythbuntu restore : how to find out database password?

Tags: mythbuntu, mythtv

I recently decided to reinstall my Mythbuntu system, as it had been upgraded in phases from version 10.x and was throwing up fairly frequent errors.

The situation as was: Mythbuntu 12.something, running MythTV 0.26. Recordings are stored on a different drive to everything else, including the database.

How I proceeded:

1. Used the Mythbuntu Control Centre's builtin Backup command to back up settings and database to the recordings drive.
2. Reinstalled Mythbuntu from an up to date ISO, wiping the system drive in the process.
3. Updated to MythTV 0.26 using the Mythbuntu repo.
4. Edited fstab to mount the recordings drive in the appropriate place.
5. Used the Mythbuntu Control Centre's builtin Restore command to restore the database and settings.

The problem: Now mythfrontend insists that it can't find the database.
My guess is that one of the things that was backed up and restored was the mysql password for the database - but presumably on a new install this is different to the old install?

How can I find out the correct password? Or, am I barking totally up the wrong tree here?
Thanks :) I'm afraid my knowledge of mysql admin is rather limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question:

I was barking up the wrong tree. Mythbuntu's backup and restore correctly backs up and restores the password for the database with the database, but apparently not quite everywhere that it's needed (not in ~mythtv/.mythtv/config.xml). Manually editing the password in there to match the other config files (such as mysql.txt in the same directory) solved the problem.

For anybody who *does* actually need to know the MySQL password for a given user: I don't know if there's a way to find that out, but this page gives a way to reset it to a known value: http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Category:MySQL

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, when installing a secondary frontend, I grab the DB password from the backend (stored in the mythtv user's ~/.mythtv/config.xml) and use that for configuring the DB on the secondary frontend. It's always been working, so I assume this is a legitimate way to get the needed password.